# python list and variable into html template

Tags: python, template-engine

What is the best way to get outputted list and variables nicely into 
an HTML template?

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

template = '''<html>
<title>Attributes</title>
- a
- b
- c
</html>'''
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a template engine is too heavy weight for you, you could do something like

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# Insert newlines between every element, with a * prepended
inserted_list = '\n'.join(['* ' + x for x in list])

template = '''<html>
<title>Attributes</title>
%s
</html>''' %(inserted_list)


>>> print template
<html>
<title>Attributes</title>
* a
* b
* c
</html>
```

Comment: That being said, I do like template engines and my favorite is StringTemplate - there are python bindings available as well.  http://Stringtemplate.org or you can play around with it at http://stringtemplate.appspot.com/

Comment: To give OP some more context, this is how Python documentation explains the interpolation operator: [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 5):

You should probably have a look at some template engine. There's a complete list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

In my opinion, the most popular are:

- [django.template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/)
- [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)
- [genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/)

For example in jinja2:

```
import jinja2

template= jinja2.Template("""
<html>
<title>Attributes</title>
<ul>
  {% for attr in attrs %}
  <li>{{attr}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</html>""")

print template.render({'attrs': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

This will print:

```
<html>
<title>Attributes</title>
<ul>

  <li>a</li>

  <li>b</li>

  <li>c</li>

</ul>
</html>
```

Note: This is just a small example, ideally the template should be in a separate file to keep separate business logic and presentation.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't support whitespace, meaning:

```
'\n'.join(x for x in list) #won't work
```

You'll want to try the following.

```
'<br>'.join(x for x in list)
```

Otherwise templates is the way to go!